# Php mysql using get output what I have mentioned

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Please help me to resolve this, 
I have 2 mysql tables,

tbl_product

```
id  name         title  userID
1   Phone        N95       1
2   Tab          Google    1
3   Laptop       Toshiba   1
4   PhoneNext    Nokia     2
5   Mp3 Player   Apple     2
6   Gallexy      Samsung   3
7   Hard         320GB     6
```

tbl_user

```
id selName
1  Jhon
2  Khan
3  Mohomad
4  Ann
6  Ricky
```

I need to get Like this output joining with these two tables,

```
Phone N95 (userID = 1)

Tab Google (userID = 1)

Laptop Toshiba (userID = 1)
```

**Jhon (id=1)**

```
PhoneNext Nokia (userID = 2)

Mp3 Player Apple (userID = 2)
```

**Khan (id=2)**

```
Gallexy Samsung (userID = 3)
```

**Mohomad (id=3)**

Please help me guys Thanks all....

```
I Need to get Like This out put,
<table width="224" border="1"> <tr> <td width="214">Phone N95 (userID = 1)</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Tab Google (userID = 1)</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Laptop Toshiba (userID = 1)</td> </tr> <tr> <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFF99">Jhon (id=1)</td> </tr> <tr> <td>PhoneNext Nokia (userID = 2)</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Mp3 Player Apple (userID = 2)</td> </tr> <tr> <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFF99">Khan (id=2)</td> </tr> </table>
```

Comment: What have you tried? See [how can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like this?

```
Select title,userID from tbl_product 
where tbl_product.userID = tbl_user.id 
group by userID
```

Comment: No i cant't display User Name Div correclty inside while loop

Comment: I can't get tha output using PHP, NameID field show every item name beleow. But I need to get That NameID after Group duplicates,

Comment: you can store your sql query in a variable and then take out the appropriate attribute out of the variable something like this: $ch=mysql_query(//your query);$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($id3);while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ch)){
 array_push($title, $row['Title']);} and so on...

Comment: sorry it should be $ch not $id3; also $title is the array in which you will be "pushing" your output array

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_product.userID, tbl_product.name, tbl_product.title, tbl_user.selName 
FROM tbl_product
LEFT JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_product.userID = tbl_user.id
GROUP BY tbl_product.userID
```

I recommend to start reading the basics about MySQL.

### [MySQL DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

### [MySQL SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

### [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Dear SQL is correct but I can't get out put what I have mentioned above, When I call with this Query using PHP , 
UserID field show any below item Divs

Comment: Edited. It would be better for you to start with the MySQL documentation, I think.

Comment: Hey I no need to start to SQL basic , 
This is what I need to display 
Using PHP MYSQL
Thanks!
<table width="224" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="214">Phone N95 (userID = 1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tab Google (userID = 1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laptop Toshiba (userID = 1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFF99">Jhon (id=1)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PhoneNext    Nokia (userID = 2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mp3 Player   Apple (userID = 2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFF99">Khan (id=2)</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: You have to execute your query and just iterate through the returned data and create the table. So, what is the problem?